# json array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using Discord.js for creating my own discord bot, and it´s quite fun.
For role attaching i created a file, named config, where config.json (the prefix, bot token, etc) and roles.json. There i wrote

```
{
//All roles listed for the Bot
"roles" : ["role one", "role two", "role three", "role four"],

//on false -> Bot uses only the roles mentioned above
//on true  -> Bot uses all available roles exept the ones above
"UseListAsBlacklist" : false
}
```

The blacklist thing is for later, it´s unused atm so ignore. Then the code for my role thing first is written

```
const roles = require(".config.roles.json");

    if(message.member.roles.some(r=>[${roles.roles}].includes(r.name))) {
        console.log(`User has one of those roles`);
    } else {
        console.log(`no available roles attached`);
    }
```

because in the tutorial it says

```
if(message.member.roles.some(r=>["role one", "role two", "role three", "role four"].includes(r.name))) {
        console.log(`User has one of those roles`);
    } else {
        console.log(`no available roles attached`);
    }
```

but that gives an Error. How can I attach that Array into the if loop?

Comment: "that gives an Error" — **what** error?!

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `[${roles.roles}]` with `roles.roles`. Using the require, you parse the JSON file and `roles` would have a reference to the parsed object. Then you just have to read the value of key `roles`. So `roles.roles` is that you need.